# How does the speed stay fixed when the resistance of conductor is 0?

Tags: dc-motor, basic

[image]

My textbook has the following example of hypothetical linear motor.
A current carrying conductor is placed in a magnetic field.
The conductor is attached to a variable load(pulley+weight).

**How it works:**
The force of variable load(pulley+weight) is toward right.
The magnetic force (q\$v \times B\$) is toward left.

When there is no load, the conductor accelerates toward left; the back emf grows; when the back emf reaches the supply voltage, current becomes 0, acceleration becomes 0; then the conductor moves at this ***maximum constant speed***.

When the load is increased, the conductor decelerates, back emf decreases, current rises, the magnetic force increases. When this magnetic force balances the load, the deceleration stops; then the conductor moves at this ***reduced constant speed***.

Good so far.

**Question:** My textbook says that when the resistance of conductor is 0, ***the speed remains constant at maximum speed no matter what the load is***. I don't get this. How can speed not change with load? When we increase the load, surely the back emf decreases. This means the flux linkage is less; this means the speed of the conductor is decreased. I don't see how resistance of conductor plays a role here. Help?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can speed not change with load?

If Coil R = 0 and mechanical load increases, so does electrical current in order to generate the Torque to maintain the same speed. Motors have a constant V/RPM ratio for no load. (or kV/RPM)

Yet conductors have losses so speed loss depends on the current loop resistance. (unless cryogenically cooled)

Comment: Any followup questions?

Comment: Ahh I get it now thanks to you :) \$I = \dfrac{V-E}{R}\$.  If \$R\$ is small enough, a **large change** in load/current can be balanced by a **small change** in \$V-E\$

Comment: By **small change** in \$V-E\$, I mean when \$V-E\$ is very small, a multiple of it: \$a*(V-E)\$ is also very small. Thanks again I totally get it XD